# Base Controller Action not being found, throwing 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a base controller with a method that I need on every page. It looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetCurrent(String value)
    {
        Session["current-id"] = value;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I derive my other controllers from this class.

I need to be able to call SetCurrent from any page at any time and refresh the current page.

But right now, the SetCurrent isn't recognized by any of the controllers that are trying to use it.

It throws a 404.

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Adding the code I'm using to call the URL

```
$.post('SetCurrent/' + $(this).val());
```

This is inside jquery on a select input. This part works fine and takes me to:

```
http://localhost:49191/SetCurrent/eaa2ba63-cfc6-4572-8b28-4b95df20e7e4
```

which give me:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Edit 2: These are my map routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{value}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", value = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Also, if I change the call to:

```
$.post('/Base/SetCurrent/' + $(this).val());
```

it still throws a 404.

Comment: Since there's a [HttpPost] - did you make sure to actually use POST and not GET on the caller side?

Comment: Could you show the code/form where you are calling this?  If there is not any then if its just a url navigation you need to do `GET`.

Comment: Add the calling code at the end.

Comment: Either you haven't shown any MapRoutes or your URL is missing the controller.

Comment: I just added my MapRoute. It works great usually. Just doesn't recognize the BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspect request and equivalent response with Firebug but this is looks like root path issue.

Also you are redirecting post request to index action which if example shows the whole class you don't have any index action. That's why you are getting 404.

And also i think redirection for an ajax call is a bad practice.

$.post('/Base/SetCurrent/' + $(this).val()); this is a valid call. You should write class name without the Controller.